# Chrome Malware, Redirects To Ad When I Click Link in Google?

Tags: chrome, spyware, browser-extensions

I've been dealing with this Chrome malware for awhile now, and I can't identify where it's coming from. Very occasionally, when I click on a top link in Google, it'll redirect me to a site that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5of4.png) (always the same green circle with the text "Loading"), and then to adware. The redirect is located at a new domain every time, but it's always the same green circle. Can anyone help? I only have uBlock Origin installed and I installed it via the Chrome Store. I'm on OS X Mojave. Malwarebytes turns up nothing (PUPs enabled).

Edit: Further details from a Windows instances recorded online - https://app.any.run/tasks/023a1d30-c3bf-48ec-b3a5-f1a52b94f177/

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site,

Comment: @schroeder Insight into how this specific malware works would be helpful and I suspect interesting. No "removal" info needed. I can't find any other instances of it online.